# Javascript Serial number initialization

Tags: javascript

Excuse the question.
We are currently making a Todo list like this.

https://gyazo.com/0dd4feeea3f7a27aefe6d2160944c65e

If there are 0 tasks added, the ID of the added task will be 0.
If you reassign the ID after deleting it, it will start from 1.

I want to make the specifications like a sample. What should I do?

From my point of view, I think that it may be solved by handling "let nextId = 0;".
Thank you for your guidance.

```js
{
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const addTaskTrigger = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-trigger')[0];
    const addTaskTarget = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-target')[0];
    const addTaskValue = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-value')[0];
    let nextId = 0;
    const todos = [];

    //Taskとidを作成
    const addTask = (task, id, tableItem) => {
      let idSpanTd = document.createElement('td');
      let taskSpanTd = document.createElement('td');
      //要素内のHTML文章を変更する
      idSpanTd.innerText = id;
      taskSpanTd.innerText = task;
      //生成したテーブル要素をブラウザに表示する
      tableItem.append(idSpanTd);
      tableItem.append(taskSpanTd);
      addTaskTarget.append(tableItem);
      return (task, id)
    };
    //Button要素を生成する
    const addButton = (tableItem, removeButton, createButton) => {
      let createButtonTd = document.createElement('td');
      let removeButtonTd = document.createElement('td');
      //要素内のHTML文章を変更する
      createButton.innerText = '作業中';
      removeButton.innerText = '削除';
      //生成したテーブル要素をブラウザに表示する
      tableItem.append(createButtonTd);
      tableItem.append(removeButtonTd);
      addTaskTarget.append(tableItem);
      //生成したbutton要素を生成する
      createButtonTd.append(createButton);
      removeButtonTd.append(removeButton);
      return (tableItem, removeButton, createButton);
    };
    //追加ボタンをクリックした際にtd要素を追加する処理を行う
    addTaskTrigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const task = addTaskValue.value;
      const tableItem = document.createElement('tr');
      const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
      const createButton = document.createElement('button');
      addTask(task, nextId++, tableItem);
      addButton(tableItem, removeButton, createButton);
      addTaskValue.value = '';
      removeButton.addEventListener('click', delete_element, false);

      //ボタンを押したら作業中、完了中と変わる
      createButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (createButton.textContent === "作業中") {
          createButton.textContent = "完了";
        } else {
          createButton.textContent = "作業中";
        }
      });
    })


    //チェックリスト用オブジェクト
    const todo = {
      task: 'taskSpanTd',
      status: '作業中'
    };
    todos.push(todo);

    // //削除ボタンを押した時にタスクを削除する
    function delete_element() {
      let tabletag = this.closest('tr');
      if (tabletag)
        tabletag.remove();
      updateId();

    }
    //　連番　再振り分け
    let updateId = () => {
      const tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
      const taskList = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
      nextId = 0;
      Array.from(taskList, tr => {
        nextId++
        tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent = nextId;
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Todoリスト</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Todoリスト</h1>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" checked="checked">全て
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="2">作業中
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="3">完了
  </p>
  <p></p>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>コメント</th>
      <th>状態</th>
      <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="addTask-target" id="tbody"></tbody>
  </table>
  <h2>新規タスクの追加</h2>
  <input class="addTask-value" type="text" />
  <button class="addTask-trigger" type="button">追加</button>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.  The only thing immediately clear is a mistake, is that nextId++ is incrementing before assigning the id, so the indexing starts at 1 instead of 0.  nextId++ should be placed after textContent = nextId, not before.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a few ways to do this, but one would be to sync the id number to the amount of nodes, and call a function to re render whenever an item gets removed:

```js
const cycleIds = () => {
  //find all elements with a class of "id"
  const allIds = document.querySelectorAll(".id");
  //iterate through them adding their index as the id
  for (let i = 0; i < allIds.length; i++) {
    allIds[i].textContent = "Id = " + i;
  }
}

const add = () => {

  //get input value
  const value = document.getElementById("input").value;
  //exit function if no value
  if (!value) return;
  //clear input value
  document.getElementById("input").value = "";

  //create a list item wrapper
  const newWrapper = document.createElement("div");

  //create a node to display the input value
  const newItem = document.createElement("div");
  newItem.textContent = value;

  //create an accompanying button 
  const newDelete = document.createElement("button");
  newDelete.textContent = "delete";
  //attach an onclick that removes the list item
  newDelete.onclick = function() {
    document.body.removeChild(newWrapper);
    //recycle id render when list item is deleted
    cycleIds();
  }

  //create a node to display the id value
  const newId = document.createElement("div");
  newId.classList.add("id");
  //find the amount of nodes with a class of "id" and set it as the id
  const idLength = document.querySelectorAll(".id").length;
  newId.textContent = "Id = " + idLength;


  //append the above inside the list wrapper
  newWrapper.append(newItem);
  newWrapper.append(newDelete);
  newWrapper.append(newId);

  //attach the wrapper to the body
  document.body.append(newWrapper);
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
```